# Clarification of an example of quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

What is this space look like or what is the elements of this quotient space:

$\dfrac {\mathbb {F}_{q^k}}{V}$

Given that $V$ is the span of a number of unit vectors of length $k$. 
and $F_{q^k}~$ is the vector space composed of all $k$-tuples over the finite field $F_q$ (the finite field of q elements where $q$ is a prime power)

Comment: What does length mean over a finite field? And how are you defining unit vectors if they can have a length other than $1$?

Comment: for example if k=3 the unite vector e1=(1,0,0)

Answer (score 0):

Quotient spaces are very easy for finite dimensional vector spaces. Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over $F$, and $M$ a subspace of dimension $m$. Since finite dimensional vector spaces are completely characterized by the base field and by their dimension, $V/M \simeq F^{n - m}$.

Comment: could you please give me a numerical example. I Couldn't understand what are the elements in the quotient space or what does it look like

Comment: First, figure out what the dimension of, in your notation, $V$ is. Call this $n$. Then, $\mathbb{F}_p^k / V$ behaves exactly like $\mathbb{F}_p^{k - n}$.